# Arithmetic circuits with just one threshold gate

Tags: circuit-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, cc-complexity-theory

When restricted to $0$-$1$ inputs, every $\{+,\times\}$-circuit $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ computes some
function $F:\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb{N}$. To obtain a *boolean* function, we can just add
one fanin-1 threshold gate as the output gate. On input $a\in\{0,1\}^n$, the resulting *threshold*  $\{+,\times\}$-*circuit* then outputs $1$ if $F(a)\geq t$,
and outputs $0$ if $F(a)\leq t-1$; the threshold $t=t_n$ can be any positive integer, which may dependent on $n$ but not on input values. The resulting circuit computes some (monotone) *boolean* function
$F':\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$.

> **Question:** Can threshold $\{+,\times\}$-circuits be efficiently simulated by  $\{\lor,\land\}$-circuits?

Under "efficiently" I mean "with at most a polynomial increase of size."
The answer is clear "yes" for threshold $t=1$: just replace $+$ by $\lor$, $\times$ by $\land$, and remove the last threshold gate. That is, $\{\lor,\land\}$-circuits are in fact threshold-$1$ 
$\{+,\times\}$-circuits.
But what about larger thresholds, say, $t=2$?

One can define arithmetic analogues $\#C$ of most boolean circuit classes $C$ by just using $+$
instead of OR, $\times$ instead of AND, and $1-x_i$ instead of $\bar{x}_i$. 
For example, $\#AC^0$ circuits
are $\{+,\times\}$-circuits of constant depth with unbounded fanin $+$ and $\times$ gates, and inputs $x_i$ and $1-x_i$. 
[Agrawal, Allender and Datta have shown](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000099916756) that  threshold $\#AC^0$ = $TC^0$. (Recall that $AC^0$ itself is a *proper* subset of $TC^0$; take, say, the Majority function.) In other words, constant-depth threshold circuits can be efficiently simulated by
constant-depth $\{+,-,\times\}$-circuits, with just a single threshold gate! 
Note, however, that my question is about **monotone** circuits (no Minus "$-$" as gates, and even no $1-x_i$ as inputs). Can one (last) threshold gate be so powerful also then?
I don't know this stuff, so any related pointers are welcome.

**N.B.** There is yet another interesting related [result](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097000070)  due to Arnold Rosenbloom: $\{+,\times\}$-circuits with just one *monotone* function $g:\mathbb{N}^2\to\{0,1\}$ as output gate can compute every slice function with $O(n)$ gates. 
A slice function is a monotone boolean function which, for some fixed $k$, outputs $0$ (resp. $1$) on all inputs with less (resp., more) than $k$ ones. On the other hand, easy counting shows that most slice functions require general $\{\lor,\land,\neg\}$-circuits of exponential size. Thus, one "innocent" additional output gate *can* make monotone circuits omnipotent! My question asks
whether this can also happen when $g:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ is a fanin-$1$ threshold gate.

---

**ACTUALIZATION** (added 03.11.2014): Emil Jeřábek has shown (via an amazingly simple construction, see his answer below) that the answer is "yes" as long as  $t\leq n^c$ for a constant $c$.
So, the question remains open only for **super-polynomial** (in $n$) thresholds.

Usually, in applications, only large thresholds do work: we usually need thresholds of the form $2^{n^{\epsilon}}$ for $\epsilon > 0$. Say, if $F:\{0,1\}^n\to \mathbb{N}$ *counts* the number of $s$-$t$ paths in graph specified by the $0$-$1$ input, then for $t=m^{m^2}$ with $m\approx n^{1/3}$, the threshold-$t$ version of $F$ *solves* the existence of a Hamiltonian $s$-$t$ path problem on $m$-vertex graphs (see, e.g. [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~flac/pdf/NumberP.pdf)).

(Added 14.11.2014): Since Emil answered a big portion of my question, and since the case of exponential thresholds is not in sight, I now accept this Emil's (very nice) answer.

---

Comment: Wait… exponential size?  I think you can implement a slice function in polynomial size with boolean gates, it's just a formula (which cannot re-use intermediate results more than once) that has to be exponential size.

Comment: @ Zsbán Ambrus: There are at most $S^{aS}$ circuits of size $S$, but at least $2^{2^{bn}}$ distinct $k$-slice functions already for $k=n/2$; a,b positive constants.

Comment: Threshold 2, and more generally, thresholds bounded by $2^{n^c}$, can be efficiently simulated by doing the computation in the semiring $(\{0,\dots,t\},\min\{x+y,t\},\min\{xy,t\})$.

Comment: Oh, I see now how you defined slice function. Sorry.

Comment: I’ve overstated it a bit: for exponential thresholds, this gives poly-size nonmonotone circuits. If $t$ is polynomially bounded in $n$, one can do it with poly-size monotone circuits.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: So, from threshold-t {+,x} circuit (t polynomial in n) you can get threshold-1 {+,x} circuit (= {OR, AND} circuit)? (By somehow using unary codes of intermediate results?) Could you sketch this?

Comment: You get $\land,\lor$ circuits directly. Replace each node $c$ with $t+1$ nodes $c_0,\dots,c_t$, where $c_i$ computes the Boolean predicate $c\ge i$. (You don’t need $c_0$ as it computes constant $1$, but it simplifies the expression below.) In this representation, $+$ and $\cdot$ can be simulated by $\{\land,\lor\}$ circuits of size $O(t^2)$: e.g., if $c=a+b$, then $c_i=\bigvee_{j+k\ge i}(a_j\land b_k)$.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: Very nice! I now added a remark on this. Actually, it may perhaps be worth to put this comment as an answer: polynomial threshold case was also not immediately clear (at least for me).

Comment: OK, I made it an answer.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: Thanks, Emil, for doing this. I, however, have no idea on how to handle super-polynimal thresholds, as yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is “yes” if $t=n^{O(1)}$. More generally, a threshold $\{+,\cdot\}$-circuit of size $s$ with threshold $t$ can be simulated by a $\{\lor,\land\}$-circuit of size $O(t^2s)$.

First, observe that it is enough to evaluate the circuit in $\{0,\dots,t\}$ with truncated addition and multiplication: in particular, if $a,a'\ge t$, then $a+b,a'+b\ge t$, and either $ab,a'b\ge t$ as well, or $ab=a'b(=0)$.

With this in mind, we can simulate the circuit with a Boolean monotone circuit by replacing each node $c$ with nodes $c_0,\dots,c_t$, where $c_i$ is intended to compute the predicate $c\ge i$. (We need $c_0$ only for notational convenience, it computes the constant $1$ function.) If $c$ is a Boolean input variable $x$, we take $c_1=x$, $c_2=\dots=c_t=0$. If $c$ is an addition gate, say $c=a+b$, we implement it via
$$c_i=\bigvee_{\substack{j,k\le t\\j+k\ge i}}(a_j\land b_k).$$
Multiplication gates are handled in the same way.

This takes $O(t^3)$ gates per one gate of the original circuit. As a minor optimization, we can reduce it to $O(t^2)$ by putting
\begin{align*}
c_t&=\bigvee_{j+k\ge t}(a_j\land b_k),\\
c_i&=c_{i+1}\lor\bigvee_{j+k=i}(a_j\land b_k),\qquad i<t,
\end{align*}
so that each $a_j\land b_k$ is used as an input of only one of the $c_i$ gates.